# Understanding this architecture

Tags: java, architecture, interface

I have inherited a massive system from my predecessor and I am beginning to understand how it works but I cant fathom why.

It's in java and uses interfaces which, should add an extra layer, but they add 5 or 6.

Here's how it goes when the user interface button is pressed and that calls a function which looks like this

```
foo.create(stuff...)
{
    bar.create;
}
```

`bar.create` is exactly the same except it calls `foobar.creat` and that in turn calls `barfoo.create`. this goes on through 9 classes before it finds a function that accessed the database.

as far as I know each extra function call incurs more performance cost so this seems stupid to me.

also in the `foo.create` all the variables are error checked, this makes sense but in every other call the error checks happen again, it looks like cut and paste code. 
This seems like madness as once the variables are checked once they should not need to be re checked as this is just wastinh processor cycles in my opinion.

This is my first project using java and interfaces so im just confused as to whats going on.

can anyone explain why the system was designed like this, what benefits/drawbacks it has and what I can do to improve it if it is bad ?

Thank you.

Comment: from what you describe, it sounds like interface overkill.  However, without looking more closely at all the code, it is difficult to say for sure that it is a problem.  If some methods just "pass through" but others are implemented sooner in the call chain, then this layout could still make sense.  Multiple levels of error checking, though, is probably a bad idea unless they are being turned off in production.

Comment: is it possible to ask the guy who did it? maybe he can give you some explanations or hints.

Comment: @Paul W they all just pass through, there's no getting off early. would you think it would be ok to change the initial call to somewhere further down the line to skip a few but use the main interface still ?

Comment: @aav all I ever get is go to this line in this function and change this variable, very uncreative about how it works.

Comment: @Skeith so, what to say.. if you will have to "live" with this software for significant time, and maintain it - maybe you should start thinking (and planning) about possible ways of streamlining it (cleaning, refactoring, removing un-needed complexities)

Comment: @Skeith if you have a test environment, it can't hurt to try to rip things apart.  You can always back up and you will learn the code better for trying.  Depending on your IDE, you may even be able to refactor some of the issues away in just a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at design patterns, and see if they are being used in the project. Search for words like factory and abstract factory initially. Only then will the intentions of the previous developer be understood correctly.

Also, in general, unless you are running on a resource constrained device, don't worry about the cost of an extra call or level of indirection. If it helps your design, makes it easier to understand or open to extension, then the extra calls are worth making.

However, if there is copy-paste in the code, then that is not a good sign, and the developer probably did not know what he was doing.

Comment: im worried about the extra calls on a quad core server it can take 20 minuets for the button click to take affect.

Comment: unneeded CPU cycles is not the only extra cost. sometimes unneeded complexity without good reason is even worse.

Comment: @Skeith - Although what you have described sounds very suspect, the multiple calls won't cause that kind of degradation unless they all do some extensive processing.  If there is a performance problem that you are trying to address, profile the code and see where it actually is.

Comment: @Robin performance is not what im working on at the moment I just thought while im here seeing as its starring me in the face.

Comment: @Robin i think there is a performance problem. @Skeith is not able to figure out how to manage the system and wastes time digging through the code. it is also a performance problem.

Comment: I think you need to catch the previous developer, and ask him for the rationale behind the design, and like Robin says, unless you are working on some complex algorithm or intensive processing task, it shouldn't cause a problem. Also, I don't think you will get any specific answers from us unless we can take a look at the actual code. But then, you can always refactor the code if you don't like it the way it is. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to understand what exactly is done in your software. Maybe it even makes sense.  But I've seen couple of projects done by some  "design pattern maniacs". It looked like they wanted to demonstrate their knowledge of all sorts of delegates, indirections, etc. Maybe it is your case.

Comment: tell me about it, iv been at this 5 weeks and only just today have I worked out how to trace a command through all the classes to meaningful code.

Comment: so, it can be your case. but it will help A LOT if you will try to talk to the guy who did it. maybe he still had some good reasons for it.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on the architecture without carefully examining it, but generally speaking separation of services across different layers is a good idea. That way if you change implementation of one service, other service remains unchanged. However this will be true only if there is loose coupling between different layers.

In addition, it is generally the norm that each service handles exceptions that specifically pertains to the kind of service it provides leaving the rest to others. This also allows us to reduce the coupling between service layers.

Comment: every layer is a copy paste of the last layer, there is no separation and they all throw the same custom exception